# Shell make system paths click-able when printed out by my shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am totally new on Shell Scripting, so please don't shout me if I ask something that's wrong :)

When I use my shell, and the system print's out some pages URLs the shell allowing me to click that links and view them on my browser.

The question is, can I have that same functionality for the system absolute paths printed out by my shell script ?

In example let's consider the following code example:

```
#!/bin/bash

sessions_path="/tmp/sessions"

echo "Your sessions path is ${sessions_path}"
```

The above script should print out the message `Your sessions path is /tmp/sessions`. In the result string, is it possible to make the `/tmp/sessions` part click-able, and when the user click on that open a new window of the file manager pointing in this folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a function of the shell, but rather the terminal (the program you use to get to the shell prompt) you are using.

You'll have to configure the terminal used and modify what it allows to be clicked/hyperlinked.

Comment: Ah OK! I see. I didn't knew how that functionality works. Actually I am a Windows child, so I am no yet so comfortable with Linux. I will mark your answer as correct in about 9 minutes. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: In Windows, the _command prompt_ (`cmd.exe`) acts as your terminal, and what runs inside it is the shell. In Linux, you can have multiple terminals (programs that let you access the command line) and multiple shells (the program that controls the command line). Note that the word _"command line"_ is generally Windows-specific; in Linux land we use "shell" for the "prompt", and "terminal" for the program used to access the prompt.

Comment: Nice to know !! Thanks again .. !! :) Have a nice 2015 !! :)